# Difference between a constructor with parameters and without parameters in c#

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

This question might look very simple for many, but I really want to understand the following

- Difference between the two classes along with the `Name` property
- Benefits of using one among the two
- When & Where to use such (any practical applications)?

**Code:**

```
public class test1
{
    public test1()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class test2
{
    public test2(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleTest
{
    public void PerformTests()
    {
        test1 Test1 = new test1();
        Test1.Name = "Power Measurements";

        test2 Test2 = new test2("Power Measurements");
    }
}
```

to be more precise please consider the objects **Test1 & Test2**.

any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The physical difference between the two classes is only in the constructor. One has a parameter; one doesn't.

The semantic difference is that `test2` *requires* a `Name`. In `test1`, it is optional. So you would use `test2` if you want to force a caller to provide a name.

Answer (score 1):

When your property is ment to be read-writable there might be no difference on both. It depends on if it is required property or optional one. When you define a constructor you force the property to be provided. In the other case your property might or might not be set by the user of your class. You may however provide a default-value for it within your constructor in this case.

However often you won´t need to have a writable property thus you can make it read-only (by declaring a private setter e.g.) and set its value within the constructor. In this case you have to provide the value within the constructors parameter.

```
public class TestClass
{             
     public string Name { get; private set; }

     public TestClass(string name)
     {
         this.Name = name;
     }    
}
```

Now you may set the value of the property by providing it within the constructor. Once it has been set it is immutable (at least **outside** the scope of the class). However you may change the value **inside** the class. If you want to avoid this also you have to provide a `readonly`-backing-field for the property.

```
public class TestClass
{             
     private readonly _name;
     public string Name { get { return this._name; } }

     public TestClass(string name)
     {
         this._name = name;
     }    
}
```

This is the safest appraoch to avoid that the value you initlally provided within the constructor is ever changed either by a user of your class or within the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors with parameters force the developer to supply any required variables when creating and instance of the object.

For example, lets say each object should have a 'Name' but it cant be changed after the object is created.

```
public class TestClass
{
     private string _name = string.Empty;

     public string Name
     {
         get{ return _name; }
         private set { _name = value; }
     }

     public TestClass(string name)
     {
         this.Name = name;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor with no parameters is default, you can use it to create an object without any further specification, using a parameter you can specify a name or something else during the creation of the object. You should probably read more about the basics of object oriented programming to get a better understanding.